# Whitelisting Marketing Cloud for SSJS and custom Journey Builder activities

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, httprequest, custom-activity, mulesoft

I'm trying to get Mulesoft open for data coming from the following sources in Marketing Cloud:

1. custom Journey Builder activities
2. server-side JavaScript (HTTP requests)
3. Ampscript (HTTP requests)

Running a script that requests the sender IP address I got list of a few IP addresses belonging to an IP range that is described in the documentation article ["IP Addresses for Inclusion on Whitelists"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_ip_addresses_for_inclusion_on_whitelists.htm&type=5) as:

> For outbound communication, such as tokenized sending, FTP file transfer, and HTTPGet, as part of Marketing Cloud. This includes functionality to support, but is not limited to, Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 integration.

I understand the range mentioned there covers both SSJS and Ampscript.

Do custom Journey Builder activities also use the same IP range?

Requests sent by Journey Builder are HTTP Posts, but I don't know If they are treated the same and for example are not covered by the `Asynchronous Web Service API endpoint` also mentioned in that article.

Comment: Are Custom Journey Apps build on Mulesoft? Or Custom Activity App just request data from it?